# Assertion Failed: You included Ember Data but didn't define OL_segments.Store

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm currently getting this error in my console:

```
Assertion Failed: You included Ember Data but didn't define OL_segments.Store
```

I've done a search already and previously, this was an issue in older versions of Ember. See https://github.com/getoutreach/epf/issues/113 and https://github.com/emberjs/website/issues/629 .

However, the current versions I am running are Ember 1.7, Handlebars 1.3 and jQuery 1.11. This page seemed to render fine yesterday, and I'm wondering what the cause might be as I've just recently updated my gems in my rails project.

[image]

Comment: How do you have ember installed? The `ember-rails` gem, via `ember-cli`, or...?